Why is a norm the square root of an inner product?
This might sound like a dumb question, but I've been stuck trying to understand this.
With the way an inner product is defined, for a vector space V and some value $y \in V,$ $\langle x, y\rangle \lt 0$. An example of this is the dot product on $\mathbb R^2$ (e.g., $[1, 1]^T$, $[-1, -1]^T$)
At least, this is my understanding. Now, I learned that any inner product induces a norm. And it's defined as the square root of the inner product. This is a problem because norms assign vectors a positive real valued number. If it's something wrong with my understanding of the definition of an inner product, I still want to know why the norm is the square root of the inner product and not some other function.

Any inner product induces a norm, but not every norm comes from an inner product: for instance, the norm $||(x,y)||=|x|+|y|$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not associated to an inner product.

If we have a right triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and $c$ is the hypotenuse, why do we take the square root to get $c$?

"This is a problem because norms assign vectors a positive real valued number." I see no problem here. The square root of a positive number is a positive number, and inner products are positive-definite by definition. As for why the square root is there: What happens to $\langle x, x \rangle$ if I multiply $x$ by some constant $a$?

At heart, this is related to the Pythagorean theorem. The norms given by inner products are like Euclidean distances.

The standard Euclidean norm satisfies the Parallelogram Law and hence there is an inner product such that $|\langle x,x\rangle| = |x|$

"The norm is the square root of the inner product" is an oversimplification. An inner product takes two vectors, a norm takes just one vector.
If $\langle \bullet, \bullet \rangle$ is an inner product, there can be vectors $x, y$ such that $\langle x, y\rangle < 0$ (and in fact there always are, except if the vector space is trivial: consider $\langle x, -x\rangle$ for nonzero $x$). The norm induced by this inner product, on the other hand, is defined by $||x|| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$, and $\langle x, x\rangle ≥ 0$ always holds by definition of an inner product. That is, the inner product of a vector with some arbitrary other vector can be negative, but the inner product of the vector with itself is always nonnegative.
Also, beware that although an inner product can be used to define a norm, not every norm can be defined by means of an inner product.

That cleared up my question about norms assigning vectors a real valued number. Thanks!!

Jean’s answer covers everything but the one question of “why the square root?” This has a simple answer: otherwise, the norm would not be homogenous. In other (less formal) words, the units would be wrong.
To see this, let’s take the vector $x$, some inner product, and a positive scalar $a$, which you may interpret as changing the units.
$$\langle ax,ax \rangle  =a^2 \langle x,x \rangle$$
Scaling by $a$ scaled the whole inner product by $a^2$! Think about what this would mean if we wanted the norm to represent the magnitude of velocity for instance. The units of speed and velocity would be different! Taking the square root is exactly the function which maps $a^2$ to $a$, and thus makes the units the same (and one of the norm axioms satisfied).

Thank you, this makes sense!
